# Differential eqs gives the error: 'is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \ and so cannot be used for replacing'

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve these differential equations, so I can get a list of y values for different values of R. I only keep getting the message: 'is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \ and so cannot be used for replacing.'

I've tried to use ?NumericQ, but I didn't manage to get rid of the errors or I used ?NumericQ wrong . The script worked perfectly when I didn't have the differentialeqY  and the stuff that did go with the differntialeqY (like the boundary conditions of y). I would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

```
Cconst = 2.99792458*10^(10);(*speed of light in cm/s*)


Gconst = 6.67408*10^(-8);
msun = 1988500*10^(24)*10^3;
msunincm = Gconst/Cconst^2*msun;
densitypercm2 = Gconst/Cconst^2;
Centi = 1/msunincm // N;
second = Cconst/msunincm // N;
gram = 1/msun // N;
gcm3 = gram/Centi^3 // N;
km = 10^5*Centi;
press = gcm3/Cconst^2;
dynecm2 = gcm3/Cconst^2;
rmin = 1*10^(-10);
rmax = 15.;
rhotest = 10^(15) gcm3;
(* This takes the K values from the Read paper, multiplied with c^2 \
to get the right units, and converts
them into units where c=G=msun=1*)

Kgeom[Kcgs_, gamma_] := Kcgs *dynecm2/(gcm3^gamma)
pressure[\[Rho]_, K_, \[CapitalGamma]_] := K*\[Rho]^\[CapitalGamma] ;
density[p_, K_, \[CapitalGamma]_] := (p/K)^(1/\[CapitalGamma]) ;
epsilon[p_, K_, \[CapitalGamma]_, 
  a_] := (K/(\[CapitalGamma] - 1)) * 
   density[p, K, \[CapitalGamma]]^\[CapitalGamma] + (1 + a )*
   density[p, K, \[CapitalGamma]] 
(* mass-energy density *)
(* Polytrope crust definition, first is the \
K-value, second is gamma, third is border-value;in geometric units *)

aFun[a_, g1_, g2_, Kval1_, Kval2_, 
   rhoVal_] := (epsilon[pressure[rhoVal, Kval1, g1], Kval1, g1, a]/ 
     rhoVal) - 1 - (Kval2/(g2 - 1))*rhoVal^(g2 - 1);
ReadCrustgeom := {
   {Kgeom[6.8011*10^-9* Cconst^2, 1.5842], 1.5842, 
    2.44034*10^7 gcm3},
   {Kgeom[1.06186*10^-6 * Cconst^2, 1.28733], 1.28733, 
    3.78358*10^11 gcm3}, 
   {Kgeom[5.32697*10^1* Cconst^2, 0.62223], 0.62223, 
    2.62780*10^12 gcm3}, 
   {Kgeom[3.99874*10^-8 * Cconst^2, 1.35692], 1.35692}};
(* rho1 and and rho2 from Read*)
\[Rho]1 = 10^14.7 gcm3;
\[Rho]2 = 10^15.0 gcm3;

EosDefinitions := {{"EoS", "Pressure p1",  "\[CapitalGamma]1", 
    "\[CapitalGamma]2", "\[CapitalGamma]3"},
   {"SLy", 10^34.384 dynecm2, 3.005, 2.988, 2.851}, 
   {"ENG", 10^34.437 dynecm2, 3.514, 3.130, 3.168}, 
   {"MPA1", 10^34.495 dynecm2, 3.446, 3.572, 2.887}, 
   {"MS1", 10^34.858 dynecm2, 3.224 , 3.033, 1.325},
    {"MS1b", 10^34.858 dynecm2, 3.456, 3.011, 1.425}, 
   {"H4", 10^34.6692 dynecm2, 2.909, 2.246, 2.144}, 
   {"ALF2", 10^34.616 dynecm2, 4.070, 2.411, 1.890}};

mrModule[dens_, gamm1_, gamm2_, gamm3_] := 
 Module[{p1 = dens, \[CapitalGamma]1 = gamm1, \[CapitalGamma]2 = 
    gamm2, \[CapitalGamma]3 = gamm3}, 
  K1 = const /. 
    Solve[pressure[\[Rho]1, const, \[CapitalGamma]1] == p1 , const][[
     1]]; (* since p1 is known we can calculate the value of K1*)
  
  K2 = (K1*\[Rho]1^\[CapitalGamma]1)/(\[Rho]1^\[CapitalGamma]2);
  K3 = (K2*\[Rho]2^\[CapitalGamma]2)/(\[Rho]2^\[CapitalGamma]3);
  \[Rho]0 = (K1/
      ReadCrustgeom[[4, 
       1]])^(1/(ReadCrustgeom[[4, 2]] - \[CapitalGamma]1));
  pPW[rho_] := Piecewise[
    {{pressure[rho, ReadCrustgeom[[1, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[1, 2]]],  
      0 < rho <= ReadCrustgeom[[1, 3]]},
     {pressure[rho, ReadCrustgeom[[2, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[2, 2]]],  
      ReadCrustgeom[[1, 3]] < rho <= ReadCrustgeom[[2, 3]]},
     {pressure[rho, ReadCrustgeom[[3, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[3, 2]]],  
      ReadCrustgeom[[2, 3]] < rho <= ReadCrustgeom[[3, 3]]},
     {pressure[rho, ReadCrustgeom[[4, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[4, 2]]],  
      ReadCrustgeom[[3, 3]] < rho <= \[Rho]0 },
     {pressure[rho, K1, \[CapitalGamma]1],  \[Rho]0 < 
       rho <= \[Rho]1},
     {pressure[rho, K2, \[CapitalGamma]2],   \[Rho]1 < rho <= \[Rho]2},
     {pressure[rho, K3, \[CapitalGamma]3],  rho >  \[Rho]2}}];
  aMinus3 = 0;
  aMinus2 = 
   aFun[aMinus3, ReadCrustgeom[[1, 2]], ReadCrustgeom[[2, 2]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[1, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[2, 1]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[1, 3]]];
  aMinus1 = 
   aFun[aMinus2, ReadCrustgeom[[2, 2]], ReadCrustgeom[[3, 2]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[2, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[3, 1]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[2, 3]]];
   a0 = aFun[aMinus1, ReadCrustgeom[[3, 2]], ReadCrustgeom[[4, 2]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[3, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[4, 1]], 
    ReadCrustgeom[[3, 3]]];
  a1 = aFun[a0, ReadCrustgeom[[4, 2]], \[CapitalGamma]1, 
    ReadCrustgeom[[4, 1]], K1, \[Rho]0];
  a2 = aFun[a1, \[CapitalGamma]1, \[CapitalGamma]2, K1, K2, \[Rho]1];
  a3 = aFun[a2, \[CapitalGamma]2, \[CapitalGamma]3, K2, K3, \[Rho]2];
  epsiPiece[pressure_] := Piecewise[
    {{epsilon[pressure, ReadCrustgeom[[1, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[1, 2]], 
       aMinus3],  0 < pressure <= pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[1, 3]]]},
     {epsilon[pressure, ReadCrustgeom[[2, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[2, 2]], 
       aMinus2],  
      pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[1, 3]] ] < pressure <= 
       pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[2, 3]]]},
     {epsilon[pressure, ReadCrustgeom[[3, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[3, 2]], 
       aMinus1],  
      pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[2, 3]]] < pressure <= 
       pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[3, 3]]]},
     {epsilon[pressure, ReadCrustgeom[[4, 1]], ReadCrustgeom[[4, 2]], 
       a0],  pPW[ReadCrustgeom[[3, 3]]] < pressure <= pPW[\[Rho]0] },
     {epsilon[pressure, K1, \[CapitalGamma]1, a1],  
      pPW[\[Rho]0]  < pressure <= pPW[\[Rho]1]},
     {epsilon[pressure, K2, \[CapitalGamma]2, a2],   
      pPW[\[Rho]1] < pressure <= pPW[\[Rho]2]},
     {epsilon[pressure, K3, \[CapitalGamma]3, a3],  
      pressure >  pPW[\[Rho]2]}}];
  mmPrimePoly := 
   4 \[Pi] r^2 * epsiPiece[p[r]]  == Derivative[1][mm][r];
  TOVPoly := (mm[r] + 
        4 \[Pi] r^3 p[r]) ((p[r] + 
          epsiPiece[p[r]] )/(r (r - 2 mm[r])) ) + 
     Derivative[1][p][r] == 0;
  Differentialequation := 
   ry'[r] + y[r]^2 + 
     y[r] (1 - (2 mm[r])/r)^-1 (1 + 
        4 \[Pi] r^2 (p[r] - epsiPiece[r])) + 
     r^2 (4 \[Pi] (1 - (2 mm[r])/r)^-1 (5 epsiPiece[r] + 
           9 p[r] + (epsiPiece[r] + p[r])/D[p[r], epsilon[r]]) - (
        6 (1 - (2 mm[r])/r)^-1)/
        r^2 - (2/r (mm[r] + 4 \[Pi] r^3 p[r])/(r - 2 mm[r]))^2) == 0;
  solutionsME[\[Rho]0_] := NDSolve[
     {mmPrimePoly,
      TOVPoly,
      Differentialequation ,
      p[rmin] == pPW[\[Rho]0], 
      WhenEvent[p[r] - rmin, "StopIntegration"],
      y[rmin] == 2,
      mm[rmin] == epsiPiece[pPW[\[Rho]0]]*4/3*\[Pi]*rmin^3},
     {mm, p, y},
     {r, rmin, rmax}, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 15, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 25] // Quiet;
  Radius[\[Rho]_] := (p /. solutionsME[\[Rho]][[1]])[[2]] ;
  mass[\[Rho]_, r_] := (mm[r] /. solutionsME[\[Rho]][[1]]) ;
  differentialeqY[\[Rho]_, r_, 
    mm_] := (y[r] /. solutionsME[\[Rho]][[1]]) ;
  radiusTable = Table[{
     i,
     10^(i) gcm3,
      Radius[10^(i) gcm3]},
    {i, 13.5, 15.9, 0.4}];
  analysis = MapThread[List, {radiusTable[[All, 3]],
     differentialeqY @@@ 
      MapThread[
       List, {radiusTable[[All, 2]], radiusTable[[All, 3]]}]}];
  MapThread[List, {analysis[[All, 1]], analysis[[All, 2]]}]]

mrResult = 
  ParallelMap[mrModule @@ # &, EosDefinitions[[2 ;; All, 2 ;; All]]];
```

This is the latex expression for the equation:

```
r y'(r) + y(r)^2 +y(r) \bigg[1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}\bigg]^{-1}(1+4 \pi r^2[p(r) - \epsilon(r)])  
+ r^2\big(4\pi \bigg[1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}\bigg]^{-1}\bigg[5\epsilon(r) + 9p(r) + \frac{\epsilon(r) + p(r)}{\frac{dp}{d\epsilon}} \bigg] 
- \frac{6\bigg[1-\frac{2m(r)}{r}\bigg]^{-1}}{r^2} - \bigg(\frac{2}{r}\bigg[\frac{m(r) + 4\pi p(r) r^3}{r - 2m(r)}\bigg]\bigg{)^2}\big)=0
```

and this is just a picture of the equation

[image]

Comment: Could you add `Cconst` to your code?

Comment: I think your WhenEvent is wrong.  p[r] - rmin is no event. Did you mean: p[r] - rmin==0?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I've set the c constant to 1 and at the end of my calculation I will add it to my plot.

Comment: @DanielHuber  I've used this in my script without differentialeqY and it worked perfectly. If i change p[r] -rmin to p[r] - rmin ==0 it that previous script, the results where the same.

Comment: Equation `Differentialequation` has several typos. Could you add Latex expression for this equation?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I've added the latex expression and a picture of the expression. I also added Cconst

Comment: I just changed the script a little bit. In the DifferentialequationY I changed D[p[r]/epsiPiece[r]] to D[p[r]/epsilon[r]]

Comment: This expression obviously wrong `D[p[r], epsilon[r]]`. In your code there is a function 4 variables `epsilon[p, K, \[CapitalGamma], a]`. What do you mean when use `epsilon[r]`?